# resistor drift via temp messing with ADC readings in voltage divider

Tags: temperature, voltage-divider, drift

I am voltage dividing 0 to 64 VDC down to 0 to 1.8 volts via a simple voltage divider.

I am using 1% resistors.

The problem is that the readings from the ADC in my beaglebone black seems to be drifting over time in that say 48 volts is not consistently reported as the same ADC reading day to day.

The attached chart shows the drift.  Each day should look identical and does via a Fluke meter.

My circuit is

Vin -> 4700ohm -> 120ohm -> gnd

The ADC sense pin attaches between the 4700ohm and the 120ohm resistors.  The ADC reference gnd is attached to gnd.

The +5vdc  power supply that supplies the microprocessor and ADC is isolated from the above circuit except for a common gnd.

Should I expect so much drift via the voltage divider (presumedly due to temperature)?

[image: chart of voltages]

Comment: Relevant, but not enough to explain your results: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5700/tolerance-of-voltage-dividers-with-different-values-for-r1-and-r2

Comment: What are you measuring? Are you sure its behavior couldn't drift a per cent or two over a week? Presumably your system is also temperature dependent (explaining the 24 hour cycles), has the weather/environment remained exactly the same temperature during the week you measured?

Comment: You're blowing away half a watt in the 4.7K- what are the specs? The daily variation is lead-acid battery voltage with temperature and solar charging? (just guessing where the 48V comes from).

Comment: You're also not going to get 1.8 volts with those resistors. 1.6 volts is more like it. And please expand on exactly how you are checking the system with a Fluke. Once per day? Once per hour?

Comment: In general, a voltage divider has no temperature dependency, if the resistors are of the same kind. And ~15% also is too much for a bad voltage reference. May be you are using the supply voltage as reference? (still quite much)

Comment: Check if it is a temperature dependent problem by either blowing hot air on the resistors to heat them up using a hair dryer, or cool them down using a pressurized air can.  If you are using an  internal reference voltage for the ADC, try using an external one like the Microchip [MCP1541](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21653C.pdf) which is essentially flat from 0°C to 75°C.

Comment: To answer the question, we would need to know the part numbers for the resistors, the specific ADC you are using (with a 120 ohm effective source resistance, it may not convert properly). As already noted, the 4.7k is dissipating 1/2W, and as that gets toasty, its resistance may very well change.

Comment: More details: Lead acid solar battery array. 1.6VDC max was intentional to stay clear of ADC limit.  Beaglebone black ADC documentation says R2 in the voltage divider must be less than 1000 ohms.

I will try the heat/cool strategy suggested by tcrosley to test the issue.  I will also plan to try the Ghosh solution presented below

Comment: Temperature measurements with the DMM were made randomly at various times of day over several days.

Comment: This site discusses the low impedence requirement of the beaglebone black ADC:

http://www.alfonsomartone.itb.it/hclbmf.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one time I have experienced a similar cyclic drift in a resistive voltage divider, one of the resistors was exposed to a varying airflow from a nearby device fan. Since my divider was initially similar to yours, the higher resistor was dissipating a lot of heat. In your case, at a full-scale of 64 volts, the 4.7k resistor dissipates around 0.8 Watts - which is a lot.

A solution would be to use a divider consisting of 620k and 18k, thus reducing heat generation massively. If the ADC requires a lower impedance source, a single-supply rail-to-rail op-amp (e.g. [OPA2192](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2192.pdf))powered from the +5V isolated supply would be used as a buffer (voltage follower).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6RESh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Why this works:**

The current through the resistors is reduced, hence reducing heat generation. Thus the temperature of the resistors does not rise significantly. This ensures that differential thermal drift, and especially change in temperature due to external cooling such as airflow, has much lower impact.

Comment: Why not use 5 V supply for both Opamp and Resistor divider?

Comment: @Umar The OP's purpose of using the resistor divider is to measure some input voltage which could go up to 48 (or 64) Volts DC, using an ADC which supports up to 1.8 Volts input. By putting the voltage divider across the 5 Volt rails, the ADC wouldn't really be measuring anything meaningful - just a static voltage.

Comment: oops! I go it. i was under wrong impression of something. Thanks